# pico getting started guide "build step" not available

Tags: eclipse, embedded, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi-pico

In the Pico getting started guide:

https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf

.. step 10.1.1.3 ..
.. right click of the project Build option ..
.. is not available?

Using latest Eclipse 2023-12 Embedded edition.

Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

No Build configurations show up but I can manually make one if I knew how.

Is there a tutorial on how to set this up manually?

I can type inside the location field and set the path to arm-none-eabi-gcc.

Then a build button appears and I can run but it has no input file or other parameters and variable.

Not sure what to do.

The guide says all I should have to do is press the build button.
The previous steps of installing cmake and converting to an Eclipse project seemed to work with no errors.

Comment: IMHO, tagging this question as C will just make to focus people that doesn;'t know about eclipse IDE.  You are going to get many people pissed off.  Please, eliminate the `C` tag.  All others can remain (I'm not an expert) but your question is not about C programming at all.

Comment: Did you do exactly as described? "_Right click on the **project** in the **project explorer**, and select Build._" (Emphasis by me.) You need the view "Project Explorer" visible, with your project selected. On that project, right click. -- Actually, my Eclipse 2323-12 has "Build Project", not just "Build". -- Additionally, the main menu has "Build Project" in the tab "Project". -- The IDE's built-in help system has a lot of helpful chapters, prepare for some time to find your way and to read.

Comment: Tagged "C" as it determines the build tools and cause many who do Python to complain.    I followed the guide exactly three times.   I have to assume it worked at one time so the current versions I listed have to be the issue.